# Finding the force of mortality at (x+t) from the force of mortality at x

Tags: derivatives, probability-distributions, proof-writing, actuarial-science

Let $\mu_x$ be the force of mortality and $S_X(x)$ the survival function

I have the proof that $\mu_x=\frac{-d(ln(S_X(x))}{dx}$

but then it is deduced that $\mu_{x+t}=\frac{-d(ln(S_X(x+t))}{dt}$

Could you please explain me how $dx$ became $dt$?

Thank you

Comment: In  this calculation you are holding "x" constant and the **variable** is "t".

Comment: Yes, but how is it possible to do that ? For someone in my level of understanding I just know if we change $x$ to $x+t$ in $ \mu_{x} $we should change $x$ everywhere in the equation to $x+t$ wich will give $d(x+t)$ in the denominator. Could you explain more please?

Comment: $d(x+t)=dt$ if $x$ doesn't vary with $t$.

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer in the comment section .

$\mu_x(x)$ is the force of mortality at age x but we want to find  $\mu_{x+t}$ in order to find ${t}P_{x}$ = Pr(X>x+t/X>x)$ where X is a r.v representing the age at death.

$\mu_x=\frac{-d(ln(S_X(x))}{dx}$

<=>

$\mu_{x+t}=\frac{-d(ln(S_X(x+t))}{d(x+t)} =\mu_{x+t}=\frac{-d(ln(S_X(x+t))}{d(x)+d(t)} $ but since we are holding the age x and and want to see only the variation of $\mu$ when $t$ varies we put dx=0 and we get the answer.

Very simple and basic but didn't get it without the comments!

Thank you

Comment: Even though the idea is correct, be very careful with your mathematical formality. (Actuarial science will require this formality later on).